# Android MVVM: Is passing objects between Activities through Intents always wrong?

Tags: android, android-intent, mvvm

In the `Model`, `View`, `ViewModel`  architecture, `Activity` classes should not persist any data. Instead, it should create a `ViewModel` and load the required data from there. In turn, the `ViewModel` loads data from the persistent data.

I was wondering if it is bad practice in the MVVM architecture to pass custom objects between `Activity` classes through `Intents`. Should the custom object be stored into the persistent data, and when the new `Activity` is created, its `ViewModel` loads the object from persistence.

It might be a non-issue as passing custom objects does not necessarily constitute persistent data, but I wanted to check if this would violate the architecture.

Comment: I think,you are mixing two Things. View and its model and viewmodel belongs to one screen. So you don't really need to persist any data. If you want to exchange data between activities, it's up to you,if you pass object through intents or use some persistence layer (shared preference, db, maybe backend)